# Compiling error: cannot find -lGLU and -lGL in kubuntu linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, ubuntu

I have some problems with compiling "hello world" application in kubuntu linux 11.10. This is project file:

```
// opengltext.pro
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
QT += opengl
```

And one cpp file:

```
    // main.cpp

    #include <QApplication>

    int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
        QApplication app( argc, argv );
        return app.exec();
    }
```

i have got the following errors:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lGLU
:-1: error: cannot find -lGL
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I try find in google the solution of this problem. But didn't find.
i try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libglw1-mesa-dev
```

but this error is still taking place

What's the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need the following 2 packages:

```
xlibmesa-gl-dev
xlibmesa-glu-dev
```

-- edit --

Thanks for correction @ephemient, these were obsolete names, right names are:

```
libgl1-mesa-dev
libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: If your system reports that you already have the packages and it still isn't working, try reinstalling them via your package manager. I already the packages installed, but for some reason I was missing the required `libGL.so` files. Reinstalling fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks pR0Ps - reinstalling worked for me to: aptitude reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the the answer about installing the right libraries (sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev) you may need to add:
unix:LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/
to your .pro file, I know I needed to. Of course that path may be different if your using 32bit software or other system dependant reasons.